# Entity with excluded values in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to create an entity that has any value except the values that are defined in another entity.
For example, i have an entity that contains all the possible products categories that i use in the bot, and if the user type a value that is not in that entity i want to react in some way.
It's like a fallback but only triggered when that condition is met.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Entity extraction is based on some definite value that can be identified and separated. There should be some basic features defined for the agent to train on. Based on these trained features, the agent will look for an entity and extract it from the user's response.
If you have already defined an entity to look for, it will be extracted by the Dialogflow based on the training data. If there is nothing defined it will not be identified as an entity as the agent will be not sure what to look for.
So, what you can do is,

- Make the entity (already defined) as not required. Uncheck the "required" checkbox in the Dialogflow.
- Add the "@sys.any" in the Entity you defined and make it a composite Entity with the combination of your Entity and "@sys.any" something in the line of
  [image]
- Train your agent to look for this new Entity with your Basic Entity data and Anything else data.
- Collect this in the webhook.

  **OR** 
  You when you want to collect anything else, you can collect user utterance from the agent object and parse the data using Regex pattern of your choice.